# How do I calculate the DC output of this specific low pass filter?

Tags: filter, transfer-function, gain, low-pass

[image: Low Pass Filter]

Hi!

I am having some trouble understanding how to calculate the DC output of this low pass filter.
Also are my calculations correcet that the transfer function of the filter is:
$$\frac{R_{\text{8}}*R_{\text{9}}}{sCR_{\text{9}}+1}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Av_dc = -R9/R8  and H(s) = Z/R8 and Z = R9||1/sC

Answer (score 1):

Think of your resistances and capacitances as *impedences*. That should make things easier when you talk about feedback loops and transfer functions.

Describe your impedence function as:

\$ Z_1 = R_8 \$ and \$Z_2 = R_9 || \frac{1}{j\omega C_1} \$

(but in the Laplace domain, \$j\omega = s\$)

So your transfer function would be:

\$ \displaystyle H = -\frac{Z_2}{Z_1} \$

Negative because it is an inverting amplifier operation.

Answer (score 0):

At DC it's as if the capacitor weren't there (open circuit), so mentally remove it from your schematic and analyze the resulting circuit as the classic inverting voltage amplifier.